# Django ORM and Async

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-asyncio

So, I'm trying to create a polling system internal to django commands for fun and to learn async/django.

I'm using django_tenants, although it's not overly important. The idea is that there is a table that holds "tenants". I want to loop through those tenants in a higher infinite loop. For each tenant that isn't already in the async queue (perhaps because the process from the last time that tenant was found hasn't finished yet), I want to add a new asyncio task to be run.

My test case has this one tenant which I wait 5 seconds for to ensure I get the internal queue/loop working.

The idea is that, say there are 3 tenants: t_a, t_b and t_c, and t_a and t_c take 2 and 1 seconds respectively to run, with t_b taking 5.

I would ultimate see the infinite loop running like this:

t_c Done
t_c Done
t_a Done
t_c Done
t_c Done
t_a Done
t_c Done
t_b Done
t_c Done --- The long running one
t_a Done
....

So, t_c doesn't hold up the other tenants from being re-run.

Each iteration of the tenants fetches NEW data as tenants might get created between runs.

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Processes the webhook queue'

    def __init__(self):
        self.tenant_queue = []
        super().__init__()

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            '--schema',
            action='store_true',
            help='Process on a single schema',
        )

    async def get_tenant_queue_count(self, tenant):
        with tenant_context(tenant):
            count = await sync_to_async(Queue.objects.count)()
            if tenant.schema_name == 't_b':
                random_int = 10
            else:
                random_int = randint(1, 3)

            await asyncio.sleep(random_int)
            print(self.tenant_queue)
            print(f'{tenant.name}: {count}, time: {random_int}')
            self.tenant_queue.pop(self.tenant_queue.index(tenant.id))

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        def _get_tenants():
            return Tenant.objects.all()

        async def _main_routine():

            while True:
                tenants = await sync_to_async(_get_tenants, thread_sensitive=True)()
                for t in tenants:
                    if t.id not in self.tenant_queue:
                        self.tenant_queue.append(t.id) 

                processing_schemas = [self.get_tenant_queue_count(t) for t in tenants if t.id not in self.tenant_queue]

                await asyncio.gather(*processing_schemas)

        asyncio.run(_main_routine())
```

Now this dies everytime with

django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.

```
File "/app/app/webhook/management/commands/process_webhooks.py", line 48, in _main_routine
for t in tenants:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
self._fetch_all()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1173, in execute_sql
cursor = self.connection.cursor()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 31, in inner
raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
```

How am I supposed to loop through the tenants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh figured it out... In order to prevent actions on the QuerySet making the ORM try and run sync actions in the async function, I needed to convert the QuerySet to a list inside the sync_to_async function

```py
    async def get_queue_count(self, tenant):
        with tenant_context(tenant):
            count = await sync_to_async(Queue.objects.count)()
            if tenant.schema_name == 'company_xyz':
                random_int = 10
            else:
                random_int = randint(1, 3)

            await asyncio.sleep(random_int)
            print(self.queue)
            print(f'{tenant.name}: {count}, time: {random_int}')
            self.queue.pop(self.queue.index(tenant.id))

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        def _get_tenants():
            # THIS LINE WRAPPED IN LIST
            return list(Tenant.objects.all())

        async def _main_routine():

            while True:
                tenants = await sync_to_async(_get_tenants, thread_sensitive=True)()
                for tenant in tenants:
                    if tenant.id not in self.queue:
                        self.queue.append(tenant.id)
                        asyncio.create_task(self.get_queue_count(tenant))

        asyncio.run(_main_routine())
```

Then to make it run indefinitely and non-blocking, I simply create tasks one after the other in the loop, and track them using a simple integer check on the self.queue

This is working as expected now! Hope this help someone.

Comment: its always feasible to use `sync_to asyn`c adaptor inside `async` co-routine

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there